# Wix Bootstrap prevent temp directory use

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have builded "HelloWord" installer with the Bootstrapper Project for Wix v3 project type.

My bundle.wxs is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">

  <Bundle Name="Bundle_name"
          Version="1.0.0.0"
          Manufacturer="Producter"
          UpgradeCode="C82A383C-751A-43B8-90BF-A250F7BC2863"
          IconSourceFile="..\WpfForms\Assets\my_lovely.ico"  >

    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost">
      <Payload SourceFile="..\WpfForms\BootstrapperCore.config"/>
      <Payload SourceFile="..\WpfForms\bin\Debug\WpfForms.dll"/>
      <Payload SourceFile="..\WpfForms\bin\Debug\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll"/>
      <!--<Payload SourceFile="..\WpfForms\bin\Debug\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll"/>
      <Payload SourceFile="..\WpfForms\bin\Debug\Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.dll"/>
      <Payload SourceFile="..\WpfForms\bin\Debug\Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll"/>-->

      <Payload SourceFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.ServiceProcess.dll"/>
      <Payload SourceFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Configuration.Install.dll"/>
      <Payload SourceFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\SDK\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll"/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <Chain>
      <PackageGroupRef Id='Netfx4Full'/>
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="..\WixSetupProject\bin\Debug\WixSetupProject.msi" Id="InstallationPackageId" Cache="yes" Visible="no"/>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>

  <Fragment>
    <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId" Value="Netfx4Full" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl" Value="NetfxLicense.rtf" />

    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" Value="Version" Variable="Netfx4FullVersion" />
    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" Value="Version" Variable="Netfx4x64FullVersion" Win64="yes" />

    <PackageGroup Id="Netfx4Full">
      <ExePackage Id="Netfx4Full" Cache="no" Compressed="yes" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" Name="DotNet_4"
                  SourceFile="../WixBootstrapper/DotNet/NDP462-KB3151800-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"
                  DownloadUrl="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=164193"
                  DetectCondition="Netfx4FullVersion AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR Netfx4x64FullVersion)" />
    </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

My problem is that the work station's antivirus configured to block any activity from `temp` directories and the builded installer.exe make copy of itself as "C:\Windows\Temp{74EA5B2A-DA46-4B3F-A8E9-4FCEC4B4523C}.cr\WixBootstrapper.exe" and run it by default. So it get locked by antivirus so instalation is over on start.

Do somebody know how can i prevent WiX components from create a cache or something in temp directories and set to run any nested executable and themselfs from the curent folder, not from the `temp`?

Comment: What anti-virus is this? The system couldn't really operate without being able to write to the temp folder. Are you sure you don't have a false positive for one of your files? Maybe you can try to test your binaries on [virustotal.com](http://virustotal.com). Just zip up the binaries and upload.

Comment: Kaspersky. It allow to write but it block any executable that have been launched from temp. May be there are some white list but all application that i compile even if they have signed by the key that allow to launch them on other machines can't be launched from temp too.

Comment: So it works if you disable Kaspersky temporarily? (just have to verify). Have you tested on a virtual as well?

Comment: I don't know. I can't try this case for now. Any machine which i can use for test  have this anti-virus settings. And i think installer is fine because it have started and i see it in the ProcessExplorer and i see the action of creating temporary exe with the path that i have wrote in ProcessMonitor and the kasspersky message with the _BlockFromWinTemp_ rule name right after this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After checking Windows's group policy settings this turned out to be
>   an anti-virus blocking problem.

---

***Group Policy?***: Does the log contain something like this:

```
Error 0x800704ec: Failed to launch clean room process: "C:\WINDOWS\Temp\{AB10C981-0D7D-4AA6-857F-CC37696DB4BE}\.cr\Bundle.exe" -burn.clean.room="C:\Test\Bundle.exe" -burn.filehandle.attached=652 -burn.filehandle.self=656 -log "C:\Test\bundle.log"
Error 0x800704ec: Failed to run untrusted mode.
```

Or does it say something else? There is a group policy that can cause similar issues. [**See WiX issue 5856**](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5856).

***Anti-Virus Grace Period?***: If you are administrator, there should be a possiblity to get a temporary grace period from your anti virus I would think. So you can perform your testing. I would give your own support desk a call first and then hit the [**Kaspersky user forums**](https://forum.kaspersky.com/) if unsuccessful. Perhaps you have a Kaspersky support agreement with priority support available?

***False Positives***: I also insist that you upload your binaries to [virustotal.com](http://www.virustotal.com) to test for false positives. That you should do no matter what. [**Antivirus Whitelisting Pains**](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/antivirus-whitelisting.html) by **Bogdan Mitrache**.

> **False positives** can actually be worse than actual malware at times (so far as the malware isn't devastating)
>   because you cannot just tell the user to rebuild their machine(s). Instead you actually have
>   to fix the problem for them in a general sense. Not only does the user have a problem to fix, you have one as the vendor as well. ***How do you whitelist your product with 60+ anti-malware suites?*** You try [**virustotal.com**](http://virustotal.com) first I think (not affiliated) - to check if you actually have such a problem.

Comment: Thanks it is seems like the issue. I have checked the bundle with virustotal and there was no problems. I have no message in Application log by the way, but it is in the Kaspersky Event Log that tell that it had locked the temp bandle.exe. I have also tried this WixVariable's: `WixBundleExecutePackageCacheFolder`, `TempFolder`, `WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder`, `SendToFolder`; and changed the System TEMP variable without success.

Comment: Did you check the policy by launching `GPedit.msc` and checking the location specified in [5856](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5856)? `GPedit.msc` might not be available if you are on a tight SOE or a Windows Home edition.

Comment: I did and the Software Restriction Policies location is empty on my machine. So it is anti-virus collision only.